# Distance Metric for clustering elements in a sparse matrix

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, distance, sparse-matrix, k-means

I am attempting to cluster approximately 12000 elements based on approximately 1200 binary variables using K-means.  None of the conventional distance metrics (euclidean, manhattan, Hamming, Levenshtein) have produced satisfactory results.

I have devised the following metric.

Dist(x,y)= Min of
P(x=0|y=1)
P(y=0|x=1)

Has anyone used a similar approach to this type of problem?  Are there any obvious flaws in using this metric? I am relatively new to data mining and would appreciate any feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What is the domain you are trying to model? Can you use insights from the domain for clustering?
There is very little that can be said in this general setting. I would try [dimension reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_reduction) in order to get more meaningful features first, and cluster later, but using domain knowledge can help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Jaccard's distance over binary attributes.
Assume you are comparing 2 rows A and B.

```
M11 - is the number of attributes where both Ai=Bi=1
M01 - is the number of attributes where Ai=0 and Bi=1
M10 - is the number of attributes where Ai=1 and Bi=0
```

The Jaccard coefficient will be

```
J = M11/(M11+M10+M01)
```

The Jaccard distance will be:

```
D=(M01+M10)/(M11+M10+M01)
```