# Ideal number of clusters in Weka K-means

Tags: java, cluster-analysis, weka, k-means

I am using Weka's SimpleKMeans function to cluster 96000 terms(as word). Weka takes the number of desired cluster number as parameter. So, it gives 2 to num. of clusters default. 
The dataset I have is 96000x641000 sparse dataset. At the beginning I gave thu cluster number 10000 but I think it is too much for recommendation process.
Is there an approach to calculate #of clusters respect to an algorithm or find the ideal #of clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

K-means is not really designed for **sparse** data. Plus, it is designed for euclidean distance, and you should be aware that this is not a good choice for high-dimensional data.

Maybe the simplest argument is as follows: The *mean* of a subset will likely no longer be sparse, so it will be *anomalous* itself, and closer to the center than the actual data instances. This however means that **the means of different clusters will likely be closer to each other than the actual instances to their means**, which makes the result highly dubious.

You should at least try k-medians instead (but it is a lot slower), or other measures to preserve sparsity for the means, too. Sure: k-means *does* cluster the data. The question is, how valid the result is.

See also:

[k-means clustering in R on very large, sparse matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039646/k-means-clustering-in-r-on-very-large-sparse-matrix)

[Clustering of sparse matrix in python and scipy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10608955/clustering-of-sparse-matrix-in-python-and-scipy)

[Distance Metric for clustering elements in a sparse matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250233/distance-metric-for-clustering-elements-in-a-sparse-matrix)

[clustering on very large sparse matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177827/clustering-on-very-large-sparse-matrix?lq=1)

[K-means clustering algorithm run time and complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356720/k-means-clustering-algorithm-run-time-and-complexity?lq=1)

[How to do K-means with normalized TF-IDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281545/how-to-do-k-means-with-normalized-tf-idf)

[Mahout binary data clustering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428156/mahout-binary-data-clustering)

For a number of failure stories (= questions without a good answer) of running k-means on high-dimensional sparse / binary data.

Answer (score 1):

For K-means variant algorithms there is a rule of thumb for the initial prediction of 'k'. Generally it is suitable to take k = (n / 2) ^ 0.5 where n = number of data points.